# swift why self.tableView does not have the properties of my TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I added a `UITableView` to my `ViewController` using StoryBoard. I also defined a custom `UITableViewCell` using the StoryBoard and connected the items (a label and an imageView) from the cell to the class (using outlet). One of the properties I defined was that the tableView and the cell has a transparent background '(using Clear Color)'. When my table is displayed everything is as designed and I see the background color of the view in which the tableView is a subview.

In my app there is an icon to activate a search. When I click on the icon I open a searchBar using the code:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

The `searchController` was defined using the following code (I use `UISearchDisplayController` to be compatible with iOS 7). The function is called from `viewDidLoad()`.

```
var searchController : UISearchDisplayController!

func configureSearchController() {
    let searchBar = UISearchBar()
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.sizeToFit()

    searchController = UISearchDisplayController(searchBar: searchBar, contentsController: self)
    searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self
    searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self
    searchController.searchResultsTableView.registerClass(CategoryTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CategoryTableCell")
}
```

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath function I dequeue a cell using:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CategoryTableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CategoryTableViewCell
```

and set the values of the items

```
cell.rowLabel.text = ....
cell.rowImage.image = ....
```

Now to my problems:

1. When I enter a value in the search bar I get an exception because my `cell.rowLabel` is `nil`. I noticed that the cell returned is of type `UITableViewCell` and not my custom `CategoryTableViewCell`. Looking at other posts I figured out that if I changed the cell dequeue to use:

   ```
   self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CategoryTableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CategoryTableViewCell
   ```

the proper cell is returned.

Why? and what is this `self.tableView`?

2. And now to my real problem. The `self.tableView` does not have the properties of my `tableView`. For example, the filtered rows display with a white background so I do not see the background color of the view. Also, the first row is displayed under the `searchBar`, as if the `self.tableView` does not know that there is now a header in the `tableView`. Adding the `searchBar` to the `self.tableView` did not make any difference

   ```
   self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
   ```

How do I solve these problems?

Please note that previously I have used `UISearchController` (which is not compatible with iOS 7) and I did not have all these problems - there was no need to use `self.tableView` at all.

**EDIT**

Screenshots:

Before entering any search text

[image: Before entering any search text]

After entering "J" in the searchBar

[image: After entering "J" in the searchBar]

Notice that the first row "Judges" is under the searchBar and only the bottom part of the word show. Also, one can see that the background color disappeared.

Comment: can you post the image for your 2nd problem ?

Comment: not getting your issue exactly ? You can't set `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar` is that so?

Comment: no need to use self.tableview since in cellforrow delegate tableview reference already passed . it seems different problm , if nil result then crashing it seems number of row not managed accurately .